# How to repair the code for a custom craftbukkit 1.9.4 plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

What did I do wrong it download the plugin using crackbukkit 1.9.4.
Expected Plugin should load up actual plugin does not seem to load or nore does the command go through.

Expected: plugin load and a command available such as /isbammadyet also a help for `isbammadyet`

Actual: plugin does not load in at all

plugin.yml file

```
main:is.bamboo0w.mad.yet
version: 6.9
name: Bam Mad Yet

commands:
  isbammadyet:
    description: Tells you how mad Bamboo0w is Right NOW!.
 Also helps with luck! <br>
 XD
```

classfile

```
package is.bamboo0w.mad.yet;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class mad extends JavaPlugin {

public void onEnable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = getDescription();
    Logger logger = getLogger();

    logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " has been Enabled! (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")");
}

public void onDisable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = getDescription();
    Logger logger = getLogger();

    logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " has been Disabled! (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to use this command");
        return false;
    }
    
    int score = 0;

    score = score + 1;

    if (score <= 1) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "some text 1, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } 
    else if (score <= 2) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Want Some Burick, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } 
    else if (score <= 3) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Stop Scamming, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } 
    else if (score <= 4) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Are You Duping There " + player.getName() + "!");
    } 
    else if (score <= 5) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Watching You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    }
    else if (score <= 6) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Coming For You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    }
    else if (score <= 7) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Gonna PK You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    }
    else if (score <= 8) {  
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Your Gonna Get Banned, " + player.getName() + "!");
    }
    else {
        score = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: [ask] - can you give more details about expected vs actual results?

Comment: Isn't the plugin loading or are there errors? If there are any, please send them, too!

Comment: @zapl I've added more details

Comment: @Nightfighter001 the plugin is just not loading in I've made a plugin earlier that work I think the errors with the int state system

Comment: This is a simple test Java program as I only started programming Java 20 hours ago came from c# or scripting which gave me a Basic idea of how to do Java as there is a slight cross over in coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think this should work:

plugin.yml

```
main: is.bamboo0w.mad.yet.mad
version: 6.9
author: flyingscot5
name: Bam Mad Yet

commands:
  isbammadyet:
    description: Tells you how mad Bamboo0w is Right NOW!. Also helps with luck! XD
```

mad.java

```
package is.bamboo0w.mad.yet;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class mad extends JavaPlugin {

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = getDescription();
    Logger logger = getLogger();

    logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " has been Enabled! (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")");
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = getDescription();
    Logger logger = getLogger();

    logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " has been Disabled! (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")");
}


public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to use this command");
        return false;
    }
    int score = 0;
    score++;
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (score <= 1) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Gimme A Kiss, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 2) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Want Some Burick, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 3) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Stop Scamming, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 4) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Are You Duping There " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 5) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Watching You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 6) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Coming For You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 7) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Gonna PK You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 8) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Your Gonna Get Banned, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else {
        score = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If it still doesn't work just tell me ;)

EDIT:
Now I wrote it for you and uploaded it to my Server:
[>>Klick>>](http://minepedia.eu/Dateien/Bam_Mad_Yet.jar)

I don't know how Long I will let the file on the Server, so be fast ;D
You can run the plugin direkt but I also put the resources in the .jar so you only have to extract it (7ZIP or WinRAR?!) if you want to edit it.

EDIT #2:
plugin.yml

```
name: Bam Mad Yet
author: flyingscot5
version: 6.9
description: Tells you how mad Bamboo0w is Right NOW!. Also helps with luck! XD
main: me.flyingscot5.bam_mad_yet.Main

commands:
  isbammadyet:
```

main.java

```
package me.flyingscot5.bam_mad_yet;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class main extends JavaPlugin{

public static main getPlugin() {
    return plugin;
}

private static main plugin;
public static HashMap<Player, Integer> scores;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    plugin = this;
    scores = new HashMap<Player, Integer>();
    new L_PlayerQuit(this);
    getCommand("isbammadyet").setExecutor(new C_isbammadyet());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("\2476Bam Mad Yet \247awas loaded!!!");
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("\2476Bam Mad Yet \247awas unloaded!!!");
}
}
```

C_isbammadyet.java

```
package me.flyingscot5.bam_mad_yet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.TabExecutor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class C_isbammadyet implements TabExecutor {

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to use this command");
    }
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (!main.scores.containsKey(player)) {
        main.scores.put(player, 0);
    }
    int score = main.scores.get(player);
    score += new Random().nextInt(3);
    if (score <= 1) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Gimme A Kiss, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 2) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Want Some Burick, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 3) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Stop Scamming, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 4) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Are You Duping There " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 5) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Watching You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 6) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Coming For You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 7) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "I'm Gonna PK You, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else if (score <= 8) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Your Gonna Get Banned, " + player.getName() + "!");
    } else {
        score = 0;
    }
    main.scores.replace(player, score);
    return true;
}

@Override
public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    List<String> nothing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nothing.add("");
    return nothing;
}
}
```

L_PlayerQuit.java

```
package me.flyingscot5.bam_mad_yet;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;

public class L_PlayerQuit implements Listener {
public L_PlayerQuit(main main) {
    plugin = main;
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, main);
}

@EventHandler
public static void onPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent ev) {
    if (main.scores.containsKey(ev.getPlayer())) {
        main.scores.remove(ev.getPlayer());
    }
}

main plugin = main.getPlugin();
}
```

Watch out! I've edited the packages but the Code itself should work!

Comment: plugin still not loading up when server is ran

Comment: Ok man just figured out why it was not loading the plugin but its was a is.bamboo0w.mad.yet(.mad)   my fault but it dont function propperly it only gives one of the replies where as ever time the command is run it ment to give the next reply in the list                really sorry about my stupid mistake

Comment: Ok not sure if my comment posted or not but the problem was it only gives first response gimme a kiss XD

Comment: You solved it? If you havn't use 'new Random().next(8);'

Comment: What u mean new random().next(8)

Comment: You can set 'score' to a random Number.

Comment: sorry im not fully undertsanding what u are telling me.    but what im am after is every time the person/user does /isbammadyet it will ass score+ 1   so score 1 +1 = 2 and that will send the user message 2 which is what some burick

Comment: would u mind putting it in your awnser for me and when it works be very happy to accept ur thingy     also thank you very much man u have been a greta help to me

Comment: Do you wan't an score for every player or one for all

Comment: so if i do /isbammadyet it will add 1 to me score.    if u do /isbammadyet iit will have a seperate counting system but does not need to hold the number if player leave more like a current thing.    also id like it to add random number between 1 or 2 so if i do /isbammadyet it will have a differnt pattern when the score rolls over again

Comment: Did it, hope it works... I changed the package a little bit and the class names, too

Comment: Well Ty dude u have gone above and beyond XD

Comment: just one minor thing it seems to repeat some link 3 or 4 times before moving on would u mind hinting me where exactly it is

Comment: nvm ty so much for ur help tho got it

Comment: The Random can also give 0 back, this means score isn't changed